# vector<vector<largeObject>> vs. vector<vector<largeObject>*> in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

Obviously it will vary depending on the compiler you use, but I'm curious as to the performance issues when doing `vector<vector<largeObject>>` vs. `vector<vector<largeObject>*>`, especially in c++.  In specific:

let's say that you have the outer vector full, and you want to start inserting elements into first inner vector.  How will that be stored in memory if the outer vector is just storing pointers, as apposed to storing the whole inner vector.  Will the whole outer vector have to be moved to gain more space, or will the inner vector be moved (assuming that space wasn't pre-allocated), causing problems with the outer vector?

Thank you

Comment: You mean vector<vector<largeObject>>?  So does vector use pointers behind the scenes?

Comment: @Leif Of course they do, a vector is a dynamic array after all.

Comment: A `vector` may just be a pointer internally, but it still has an O(n) copy constructor.

Comment: @Leif -- Sure it does.  But that's not the point.  The point is that there are very few reasons for using raw pointers.  Certainly performance gain is not one of them.  The writers of the standard library have centuries of experience between them, trust that they wrote the code as efficiently as they could.

Comment: @Etienne Yes, but if you laid each object right next to each other in memory, I would assume that you 'could' achieve the same thing...unless, I think I just got it, the object size has to be known at compile time, which implies that it has to point to the array (rather than it being the actual array), as such vector<vector<largeObject>*> points to a pointer which points to a vector, yes?

Comment: No, `vector<vector<largeObject>*>` is a `vector` of pointers to `vector`s of `largeObjects`.

Comment: How about vector<vector<shared_ptr<largeObject> > > ?

Comment: @PigBen Good point, thank you very much for that advice.  Currently I have another method that returns a pointer to a largeObject, and I returned the pointer because I didn't want the object to have to be copied in memory, so under that logic I should have just returned the object rather than a pointer to it, yes?

Comment: @Leif: I'd need to know what the function does or is supposed to do to answer that.

Comment: Use whatever does what you need in the most straightforward fashion. Do you want objects, or pointers to objects? Probably the former, so use the former.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vector is internally a pointer so pointer of vector is sort of overkill.

Vector of pointers or smart pointers is usually used when polymorphic contents are needed.

In C++03 it may be expensive to insert more vectors or (erase existing ones) of your master vector but C++0x resolves even that issue with its move semantics.

It is better to switch to more suitable containers later after profiling with real data instead of trying to make it initially extremely dynamic.

Comment: I would disagree, it's not always 'overkill' if the copy constructor for T is complicated or has otherwise undesired side-effects.

Answer (score 2):

My first question would be "why are you using nested vectors?" If you don't need the dimensions of the "2D array" to be jagged, you can use a single vector and canonical 2D indexing into a 1D array (x + width * y).

That said, since vector copies T instances around when resizing, et cetera, a vector of pointers to large objects will likely be less expensive because the copies will be smaller (copying a pointer versus a "large object"). The down side is that you'll have to manage the allocations of the large objects yourself, but something like boost's shared_ptr can help (or the standard version if you have 0x support -- not auto_ptr, though). "Large object" here could be anything, including nested vectors or pointers-to-vector like in your original example if need be.

EDIT: You can also use reserve() to pre-allocate space in the vector, preventing a lot of copying if you can make guarantees about the amount of stuff you're going to shove into the vector.

Comment: He's not asking about a vector of pointers to large objects, he's asking about a vector of pointers to vectors of large objects.

Comment: I know, but a vector<T> is potentially a "large object" so the resize of a vector<vector<T>> could be expensive, whereas vector<vector<T>*> would involve less copying. I guess I should have used another a term other than "large object" since "LargeObject" also appeared in the question.

Comment: The reason for the nested vectors is exactly that, because it needs to be jaggad.  Although I do know that the inner vector size will never grow above four (so I guess I could preallocate it), but it needs to dynamically expand to 4, which means I would have to keep track of that if I used a standard array.

Answer (score 0):

I think there will be no big difference in performance in your case it is just the matter of when do you want to spend time to create objects.

Some times it is better to use `vector<vector<BigObject*>>`

Answer (score 0):

The answer with performance questions is always: performance test or profile it.

Also consider the alternatives:

```
vector< vector< LargeObject* > >,
```

or

```
vector< vector< shared_ptr<LargeObject> > >
```

What works best will depend on the operations you perform:

- Lots of constructions/ destructions
- Copies - Can they be optimised to use
  vector::swap()?
- Do you erase elements from the middle
  of the vector?

Do you want to handle the manual memory management? If the answer is no, the stick with vector > until there is a demonstrated performance issue.

To protect yourself against having to change too much code for performance reasons later, you could/should encapsulate the 2D array in a class.